# Multi-layer Via-in-pad with 0.5mm Pitch BGA in KiCad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, pcb-layers, via

I am working on a 4 layer board with an 81 pin 0.5mm pitch BGA which effectively requires via-in-pad for dropping down to other layers. Decoupling must be done on the bottom as there is no space for components on same side as the BGA for several of the VDD/GND pairs.

The pad diameter specified for the BGA package is 0.23mm (0.05 around pad, NSMD) so ideally the via should have a 0.23mm annular ring to perfectly match the pad and should be filled/capped to effectively replace the pad of the footprint to prevent wicking the solder from the balls.

An example of the required interconnect in my stack up for decoupling of power pairs is illustrated here:

```
BGA__________VDD__________GND________
            (   )        (   )
TOP -------  | |  ------  | |  ------
GROUND ----  | |  --------| |--------
3V3 ---------| |--------  | |  ------
BOTTOM ----  | |  ------  | |  ------
             [ ]___CAP____[ ]
```

In general what would be the cheapest/best option for achieving this at the required sizes?

For KiCad specifically, how can I represent this in Pcbnew so that I can generate files for fabrication?

Research leads me to believe that drill size limitations make stacked microvias seem like the best choice but this doesn't appear to be an option (DRC gives "Micro Via: incorrect layer pairs (not adjacent)"). Should I be using "blind" vias that go from top to bottom?

Comment: Microvias typically have a 0.7:1 or 1:1 depth-to-diameter aspect ratio limit, so on a 4-layer board you're not going to be able to stack them (because the middle layer will be too thick). Your inner vias will have to be mechanically drilled.

Comment: That was one of my main concerns, would it even be possible to get buried vias that small in the middle layer from most manufacturers?

Comment: Suppose you make the overall thickness 1.0 mm, with 0.1 mm outer layers (to allow 0.1 or 0.125 mm L1-L2 and L3-L4 microvias). Then you'd have a 0.8 mm inner dielectric layer. You might be able to be able to have 0.15 mm or so mechanical drills in that inner layer --- talk to your vendor --- but you will pay a premium for such small drills, as well as a premium for the multiple drilling operations.

Comment: (But 1 mm overall will make the board fairly flexible if it's bigger than maybe 5 x 5 cm. Think about whether it would need some additional stiffeners mounted)

Comment: The board is tiny, 34.25 mm x 20 mm so thickness isn't a big concern except for dielectric effects on RF transmission line widths. Could it be cheaper to aim for a much thinner board and go for stacked microvias?

Comment: To really do stacked laser-drilled microvias, you'd end up with an overall thickness of something like 0.3 mm. I have never tried to go anywhere near that thin and I don't know whether it would be a problem for the assembly shop or not (remember they'll want to handle the board in panelized form, so it will be in a much bigger piece when it goes through assembly). Of course assembly can also be done onto flex circuits, so there must be some way to handle the issue.